# How to change a variable generated by JSON in c#

Tags: c#, json, xaml, xaml-binding

I'm having issues with something that should be very easy. I'm creating a flood warning app for windows phone 8. I have an integer `Severity`, which can be anything from 1 to 4, pulled from a JSON feed. I simply want to change the int to a string corresponding to the severity, then use the strings to populate a text block via binding. Here's the code

```
namespace FloodAlertsApp
{


public class RootObject
{

    public int Severity { get; set; }
    public string AreaDescription { get; set; }
    public string Raised { get; set; }
    public string severityTxt;      

    public string getsevText()
    {

        switch (Severity)
        {
            case 1:
                severityTxt = "Severe";
                break;
            case 2:
                severityTxt = "Warning";
                break;
            case 3:
                severityTxt = "Alert";
                break;
            case 4:
                severityTxt = "";
                break;
        }
        return severityTxt;
    }
}
```

And then the xaml where i'm using the binding is as follows,

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="FloodAlertsApp.ListView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <!--<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <Image Width="Auto" Source="/nrw_logo_linear.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">

        <ListBox Name="listBoxBeaches" SelectionChanged="listBoxBeaches_SelectionChanged" Margin="10,10,10,0" Padding="0,0,0,100" Height="{Binding ElementName=ContentPanel, Path=ActualHeight}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="TemplateLayout" Margin="0,5,0,5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Stackpnl">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="28" Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=AreaDescription}"></TextBlock>
Here be the binding---->    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="28" Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=SeverityTxt}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="Raised at "></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=Raised}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Ellipse Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,5,0" x:Name="StatusEllipse" Height="50" Width="50" Fill="{Binding Path = Colour}" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>


    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

The other bindings work fine, but when i try to change from an int to a string the binding shows up as nothing.

Comment: Why you don't use Enum?

Comment: How can I use Enum in this case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, RootObject should implement `INotifyPorpertyChanged` interface, so that bindings will work properly.

Having done that you should remove public field, and add a new property called `severityTxt`(BTW it should be called SeverityText according to the C# naming convention) with only `get` accessor.

The code will be like this:

```
public class RootObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int serverity;

    private string areaDescription;

    private string raised;

    public int Severity 
    {
        get
        {
            return serverity;
        }
        set
        {
            serverity = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Severity");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SeverityTxt");
        }
    }

    public string AreaDescription 
    {
        get
        {
            return areaDescription;
        }
        set
        {
            areaDescription = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AreaDescription");
        }
    }

    public string Raised 
    {
        get
        {
            return raised;
        }
        set
        {
            raised = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Raised");
        }
    }

    public string SeverityTxt
    {
        get 
        {
            switch (Severity)
            {
                case 1:
                    return "Severe";
                case 2:
                    return "Warning";
                case 3:
                    return "Alert";
                default:
                    return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

With such implementation you should bind not to `severityTxt` but to `SeverityTxt`.
It's the basic solution, for more solid code you should consider using MVVM framework, such as MVVM Light and\or `IValueConverter`'s.

Comment: I've tried the code and NotifyPropertyChanged does not work, is it compatible with Windows Phone 8?

Comment: you should add `using System.ComponentModel;` to the file with code

Comment: Never mind that was me being dumb, it worked! (I didn't read through the entire code) Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no problems with Enums (if I got what do you want):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <ListView Name="TestListView">

   </ListView>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TestListView.ItemsSource = new[] {Severity.Severe, Severity.Alert, Severity.Warning};
    }

    enum Severity
    {
        Severe = 1,
        Warning = 2,
        Alert = 3,
        None = 4
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

you can convert easy ints into enums, for examaple

```
TestListView.ItemsSource = new[] {1, 2, 3}.Select(i => (Severity) i);
```